# How to create a JSON string from list of objects?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, nsjsonserialization

I have a list of custom objects. Every property in a custom objects is of type `String`. I have a problem to convert that list of objects to JSON string so I can send it to web service:

```
var bytes = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(data, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.allZeros, error: nil)
    var jsonObj = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(bytes!, options: nil, error: nil) as! [Dictionary<String, String>]
```

`data` is a list of objects. This should be simple thing to do and I list two days on it.

Comment: data should be an `NSData` object, so then you can create a `String` object from data

Comment: First try to convert your list of custom objects into a list dictionary. And then try to create the json. Hope it will work.

Comment: You need to write code to create either a top level array or dictionary that contains only JSON compatible objects. Then `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in Apple [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSJSONSerialization)

> An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following properties:
>
> The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary.
>
> All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull.
>
> All dictionary keys are instances of NSString.
>
> Numbers are not NaN or infinity.

So you can't use custom objects with String properties. Use a Dictionary representation of the object instead.

UPDATE:
I can give you an example in Objective-C:

Given a simple Person object:

```
@interface Person : NSObject
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *surname;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *age;
@end
```

You can create a method for getting the dictionary like this:

```
-(NSDictionary *) dictionaryRepresentation {
    return @{@"name":self.name,
             @"surname":self.surname,
             @"age":self.age};
}
```

It can be placed in a category or directly inside the class.

Comment: Can you show me how I can convert object to dictionary?